# Operators and power regularity

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Let $E$ be an infinite-dimensional complex Hilbert space.

> An operator $A\in \mathcal{L}(E)$ is called **power regular** if for all $x\in E$, $r(x,A):=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} \|A^nx\|^{1/n}$ exits.

Assume that for all $x,y\in E$, $r(x,A),r(y,A)$ and $r(x+y,A)$ exists.

> I want to show that 
>   $$r(x+y,A)\leq \max\{r(x,A),r(y,A)\} .$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have

\begin{align}
\|A^n(x+y)\|^{1/n} &= \|A^nx+A^ny\|^{1/n} \\
&\le \Big(\|A^nx\|+\|A^ny\|\Big)^{1/n} \\
&\le \Big(\max\{\|A^nx\|, \|A^ny\}\| + \max\{\|A^nx\|, \|A^ny\}\|\Big)^{1/n}\\
&= \Big(2\max\{\|A^nx\|, \|A^ny\}\|\Big)^{1/n}\\
&= 2^{1/n }\max\left\{\|A^nx\|^{1/n}, \|A^ny\|^{1/n}\right\}
\end{align}

Letting $n\to\infty$ gives

\begin{align}
r(x+y, A) &= \lim_{n\to\infty}\|A^n(x+y)\|^{1/n} \\
&\le \lim_{n\to\infty} 2^{1/n }\max\left\{\|A^nx\|^{1/n}, \|A^ny\|^{1/n}\right\} \\
&= \max\left\{\lim_{n\to\infty}\|A^nx\|^{1/n}, \lim_{n\to\infty}\|A^ny\|^{1/n}\right\}\\
&= \max\{r(x, A), r(y, A)\}
\end{align}